# How to get the value of a form field through the form class in symfony2?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, variables, field

I would like to know how to get the value of a form field through the form class in symfony2. The explanation is as below:

This is the code of the entity class:

```
    <?php

namespace Ikproj\HomeBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Ikproj\HomeBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_user", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="pseudo", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $pseudo;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $passWD;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="sexeuser", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $sexeuser;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="dateanniv", type="date")
     */
    private $dateanniv;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return User
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     * @return User
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Set pseudo
     *
     * @param string $pseudo
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPseudo($pseudo)
    {
        $this->pseudo = $pseudo;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get pseudo
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPseudo()
    {
        return $this->pseudo;
    }

    /**
     * Set passWD
     *
     * @param string $passWD
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPassWD($passWD)
    {
        $this->passWD = $passWD;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get passWD
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPassWD()
    {
        return $this->passWD;
    }

    /**
     * Set sexeuser
     *
     * @param string $sexeuser
     * @return User
     */
    public function setSexeuser($sexeuser)
    {
        $this->sexeuser = $sexeuser;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get sexeuser
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getSexeuser()
    {
        return $this->sexeuser;
    }

    /**
     * Set dateanniv
     *
     * @param \DateTime $dateanniv
     * @return User
     */
    public function setDateanniv($dateanniv)
    {
        $this->dateanniv = $dateanniv;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get dateanniv
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getDateanniv()
    {
        return $this->dateanniv;
    }
}
```

And this is the code of the form class (the form builder):

```
    <?php

namespace Ikproj\HomeBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class UserprofilechangeType extends AbstractType
{
     /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('sexeuser', 'text');
        $def = $builder->add('sexeuser', 'text');
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Ikproj\HomeBundle\Entity\User'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'ikproj_homebundle_user';
    }
}
```

Actually, what I would like to know is how to put the value of the field "sexeuser" inside the variable `$def`. In other words, how shall I change this line `$def = $builder->add('sexeuser', 'text');` in order to get the value of the field `sexeuser`?

Comment: Well, do you have any idea about how to set the default value of a form Combobox field as the value in the database in Symfony2?. This is a question that I asked yesterday about such topic, this is its link:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27170082/how-to-set-the-default-value-of-a-form-combobox-field-as-the-value-in-the-databa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27170082/how-to-set-the-default-value-of-a-form-combobox-field-as-the-value-in-the-databa)

Answer (score 1):

You need dynamically modify Form using Form Events:

In this case, everything happens before loading data into the form (PRE_SET_DATA)

```
// src/Acme/DemoBundle/Form/Type/FriendMessageFormType.php
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class FriendMessageFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('subject', 'text')
            ->add('body', 'textarea');
        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function (FormEvent $event) {
                $data = $event->getData();
                var_dump($data);die;
            }
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'acme_friend_message';
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
    }
}
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

Comment: Well, it didn't work, I tried that and it just displays all the data in database. By the way, do you have any idea about how to set the default value of a form Combobox field as the value in the database in Symfony2?. This is a question that I asked yesterday about such topic, please have a look at this link : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27170082/how-to-set-the-default-value-of-a-form-combobox-field-as-the-value-in-the-databa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27170082/how-to-set-the-default-value-of-a-form-combobox-field-as-the-value-in-the-databa)

Comment: `var_dump` shows everything that is assigned to `$data`. In the next step you need to get value with the method (object) `getSexeuser()` or index (array). You not wrote in what context you want to get the value, which is why I left you open the way to all :-)

Comment: Well, I resolved it my friend, as I already said: I trying to do what is asked through my question at this link: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27170082/how-to-set-the-default-value-of-a-form-combobox-field-as-the-value-in-the-databa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27170082/how-to-set-the-default-value-of-a-form-combobox-field-as-the-value-in-the-databa)

Comment: Try this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#preferred-choices

Comment: What you gave me is really not relevant to what I was looking for!! I'm not looking for preferred_choices!!!...Any way, as I already mentioned: I already resolved my problem. Thanks a lot.